# Bind logic to ValueConverter output in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a list that I am binding to a select that is dependent on another value bound to a different select. They are tied together with a ValueConverter:

```
<option repeat.for="site of sites | filter: { project: project }">
  ${site.name}
</option>
```

Now, this may filter out everything. In this case, I want to show a single option 'No Sites Available'. I've tried doing a sexy css approach:

```
<option class="if-empty">No Sites Available</option>

.if-empty { 
  display: none;
}
.if-empty:only-child {
  display: initial;
}
```

Only problem is when toggling from empty -> non-empty, though not an option in the list, the "No sites available" option remains selected in the select. I need to get rid of it. Next thought was leverage Aurelia's `if.bind`, but I can't seem to bind to the output of the ValueConverter (for obvious reasons).

```
<option if.bind="sites == null | filter: { project: project }">No Sites Available</option>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try squirreling away the filtered result in an ad-hoc property on your select element.  Doesn't really matter where, just needs to be somewhere you can `ref`.

```js
<select ref="mySelect" filtered.bind="sites | filter: { project: project }">
  <option if.bind"mySelect.filtered.length === 0">No Sites Available</option>
  <option repeat.for="site of mySelect.filtered">${site.name}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: didn't the ref syntax change a few months back?

Comment: Capabilities were added but the original `ref="someName"` syntax was preserved.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed and I had no idea this concept existed.  I'm amazed by the capabilities of Aurelia everyday but wish more of this was documented on the Aurelia website.  I've been developing a couple apps with Aurelia since early on and have never seen this before.  (I've learned the most from your blog posts and StackOverflow!) Thanks